# Como embaçar formulários em C#

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber como posso embaçar um formulário (principal), após chamar outro formulário ou MessageBox.show(), para forçar o usuário a prestar atenção apenas no Form ou mensagem ativo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o seguinte código dentro de um botão:

```
    private void KpbRecibo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        kpbRecibo.Enabled = false;
        using (FrmRecibos frmRecibos = new FrmRecibos())
        {
            _ = frmRecibos.ShowDialog();
        }
        kpbRecibo.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Verifiquei vários post espalhados pela internet e vi alguns que falavam a respeito, mas, sempre que eu testava os códigos eu recebia uma mensagem de erro.

Código testado:

```
        using (FrmRecibos frmRecibos = new FrmRecibos())
        {
            frmRecibos.Owner = this;

            BlurEffect myBlur = new BlurEffect();
            myBlur.Radius = 5; 
            this.Effect = myBlur;


            frmRecibos.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Estou usando :

```
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;
```

Junto com a referência: PresentationCore.

Mas sempre recebo erro na linha:

```
this.Effect = myBlur;
```

Gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de vocês me ajudarem com esse problema. desde já agradeço a todos.

P.S.: Como eu disse antes, encontrei diversos post's e matérias sobre o assunto, mas, não são muito esclarecedores, pois creio que as explicações são para quem tem um nível de conhecimento muito alto, o que, claramente não é meu caso.

Comment: Forms eu conheço bem, mas esse link deve ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947504/how-to-show-a-pop-up-message-with-dark-background

Comment: Pela imagem você já passou por essa pergunta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248748/c-sharp-dialog-form-with-blur-background) do SO né?
A resposta nela não te ajudou?

Comment: Utilizando o System.Windows.Media.Effects você consegue o mesmo resultado de forma mais confiável e simples utilizando apenas 3 linhas. O problema é justamente o que eu havia falado anteriormente, a linha que mencionei logo acima simplesmente apresenta erro. Já vi que esse método funciona, só não sei porque no meu código fica apresentando erro.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um outro formulário que abre por trás da mensagem, segue um exemplo que utilizo em meus projetos:

```
public partial class FormShadow : Form
{
    //Form Pai onde está o controle a ser exibido
    public Form FormPai { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Form de destaque de controles e exibição de dicas
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_parent">Form que será escurecido</param>
    /// <param name="_control">Controle que será destacado</param>
    /// <param name="_message">Mensagem de dica</param>
    /// <param name="_opacity">Transparencia do Form, 0=Invisivel, 1=Visivel, Recomendado 0.5</param>
    public FormShadow(Form _parent, double _opacity = 0.5)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.Parent = _parent.Parent;
        //Define a chave de transparencia do form
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;

        //Define a cor do sombreamento do form
        this.AllowTransparency = true;
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;

        //Atribuição dos valores passados por parametro
        this.FormPai = _parent;
        this.Opacity = _opacity;

        //Define visual do form
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

        if (this.FormPai != null)
        {
            this.Size = this.FormPai.Size;
            this.Bounds = this.FormPai.Bounds;
            this.Location = FormPai.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            var rect = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
            this.Size = rect.Size;
            this.Bounds = rect;
            this.Location = Point.Empty;

        }
        //Fechar com ESC
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += FormHighlightControl_KeyDown;
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) //Se em modo debug, não mostra em full screen pq atrapalha acessar o visual studio
        {
            this.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        }
    }

    public static FormShadow Show(Form _parent, double _opacity = 0.5)
    {
        FormShadow instancia = new FormShadow(_parent, _opacity);
        instancia.Show();
        return instancia;
    }

    public static DialogResult ShowMessageBox(Form _parent, string title, string message, MessageBoxButtons btns = MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton dbtn = MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, double _opacity = 0.5)
    {
        DialogResult d;
        using (FormShadow instancia = new FormShadow(_parent, _opacity))
        {
            instancia.Show();
            d = MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, message, title, btns, icon);
            instancia.Close();
        }
        return d;
    }

    //Fechar com ESC
    void FormHighlightControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Aí é fácil de mostrar uma MessageBox:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormShadow.ShowMessageBox(this, "Teste de mensagem", "Mensagem de texto");
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://github.com/rovannlinhalis/WindowsFormsShadow

> Repare no override do Método OnShown, está definido para que, quando estiver rodando no visual studio, ele mostre apenas um bloco de 50x50, porque o form pode atrapalhar acessar o visual enquanto estiver depurando.